# Loading managed objects into Core Data via loop

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have `one-to-many` relationship between two entities. I'm trying to load the `many` entities via a loop, but nothing seems to be added. Here's a code example:

```
 for(int x=0; x<[_array count]; x++)
     {
          SOCommand* newCommand = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SOCommand" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
          newCommand.commandName = [(NSArray*)[_array objectAtIndex:x]objectAtIndex:0];
          newCommand.sshCommand =  [(NSArray*)[_array objectAtIndex:x]objectAtIndex:1];
          [newModule.socommand.allObjects arrayByAddingObject:newCommand];

     }
    [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

`newModule` is the "parent" and it is initialized before using:

```
SOModule* newModule = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"SOModule" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

To check if it added I tried doing the following:

```
NSArray* commands = [iteratorModule.socommand allObjects];
            if([commands count] >0){
                NSLog(@"array was populated");
            }
```

The log wasn't fired.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `arrayByAddingObject:` returns an array which you don't assign to anything.

The best solution would just to set the relationship from the newCommand object. Replace:

```
[newModule.socommand.allObjects arrayByAddingObject:newCommand];
```

with

```
newCommand.module = newModule;      //Not sure what the relationship name is here, so it might not be module
```

Also, I don't think you understand that first line of code,

```
[newModule.socommand.allObjects arrayByAddingObject:newCommand];
```

It gets the `NSSet` (a collection similar to NSArray) of `socommand` objects associated with the `newModule`, then puts it into an array form with the `allObjects` method. `arrayByAddingObject:` returns a new array with a new object which you do not do anything with.